# Should I root my phone?

Tags: root-access

Clearly I am being thrilled with this question boggling in my mind. "Should I root my phone?" What are the pros and cons? Clarify this thing to me, is it dangerous or is it better than I imagine?

Comment: Please browse our questions tagged with [rooting](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rooting?sort=votes&pageSize=50). Many topics related to this have been asked and answers.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone really gives you a hard time, and it really needs to be upgraded, then rooting is the best options.

As per Wiki says "Rooting is the process of allowing users of smartphones, tablets and other devices running the Android mobile operating system to attain privileged control (known as root access) over various Android subsystems. As Android uses the Linux kernel, rooting an Android device gives similar access to administrative (superuser) permissions as on Linux or any other Unix-like operating system such as FreeBSD or OS X."

**Pros of Rooting :**

- Install Custom ROM’s
- Can back up all the Device data onto memory card
- Can Install Awesome Themes
- Install Many Apps with Some awesome features.

**Cons of Rooting :**

- Security issues
- Malfunctions of Your Android Device
- Loss of Software warranty.

Helpful Link  :

http://www.techglitter.com/2013/08/what-is-rooting-how-to-root-android.html

Comment: "Can install Latest Version of Android" - I don't see how rooting allows me to update to a newer version of android? Neither do Custom ROMs require root - they require an unlocked bootloader and a custom recovery. I know that these are just the Pros mentioned in the linked article but I feel like they are not quite right and confuse users even more.